# Do DLC weapons level with me?

Tags: kingdoms-of-amalur-reckoning

This is just a quick question. If I had bought the DLC and then opened the box, The weapons are like very low level, will the weapons level up with me? Or should I have waited till I was a high level then returned to get the weapons?

Comment: I've never tried that, but I think that the DLC weapons are all probably configured to be starter weapons. Better than your starting gear, but not good enough to last more than a few levels before you find better gear.

Answer (score 2):

I opened the Bonus Content chest at level 17, and they were all basic level 1 gear. I then tried playing with them on a different character until level 4 or so, and they stayed the same.

**Gear you get from purchasing DLC is nothing but starting gear. It does NOT improve at any point.**

Answer (score 0):

Certain DLC level up along with the player, if left in non-accessed state at least - one time I did not touch DLC items until level 35ish, and at least with certain items, an indisputable leveling up had indeed occurred... "Special Delivery" items are case-by-case, and I believe, the amalur Wiki-fandom and many other websites, enumerate which specific ones are dynamically capable of being leveled, which specific ones will level up (if opened later), and which ones, not behaving so... I hypothesize tentatively the items the Amalur merchants are averse to paying one penny for, will be the items not scaling to one's level and lamely fixed...